# trying to install cpseis on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, getting problem with opencfe

Tags: software-installation, java

trying to install cpseis on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, getting problem with opencfe

```
% cfe -debug
/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/wrappers/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/jdk/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/jre/lib/amd64:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/jdk/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/mpich2-1.1/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/fftw-2.1.5/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib:/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/fftw-2.1.5/platforms/lib:/home/lewisgoss/madagascar/lib://home/lewisgoss/cpseis/wrappers/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2/lib
/home/lewisgoss/cpseis/thirdparty/jdk/platforms/Linux_x86_64_2.23_gfortran_mpich2//bin/java -ms512m -mx2048m -ss256k -Djava.util.prefs.syncInterval=2000000 com.conoco.cfe.client.application.DirectApplication file:///home/lewisgoss/prefs.xml
Preferences file is 'file:///home/lewisgoss/prefs.xml'
Unable to load dynamic library opencfe
Exit OpenCFE
```

Comment: It is unclear what are `cpseis`, `cfe` and `OpenCFE`? Where did you got them?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpseis/